# Zooming and Scrolling Image

Tags: c#, winforms, zooming, scrollable

In my on paint event, I'm trying to keep the image centered but also allow the user to zoom into the photo by scrolling.  When the scroll wheel shows up the image seems to be off by a little and draws on the screen cutting off the image anyone that can help?

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    if (_image == null)
    {
       base.OnPaintBackground(e);
       return;
    }
    Rectangle rect = this.DisplayRectangle;

    // Get a gradient brush and fill the background. 
    Brush backBrush =  new SolidBrush(Color.Gray);
    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(backBrush, rect);
    int x = (this.Width - (int)(_image.Width * _zoom)) / 2;
    int y = (this.Height - (int)(_image.Height * _zoom)) / 2;
    // Calculate the panning amount to keep the image centered
    Matrix mx = new Matrix(_zoom, 0, 0, _zoom, x, y);
    mx.Translate(this.AutoScrollPosition.X / _zoom - x, this.AutoScrollPosition.Y / _zoom- y);
    e.Graphics.Transform = mx;
    e.Graphics.InterpolationMode = _interpolationMode;
    // Calculate the top-left corner of the image
    
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(_image, new Rectangle(x, y, this._image.Width, this._image.Height), 0, 0, _image.Width, _image.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

    base.OnPaint(e);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i fixed it

```
        // Get a gradient brush and fill the background. 
        Brush backBrush =  new SolidBrush( Color.Gray);
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(backBrush, rect);
       
        int x = (this.Width - (int)(_image.Width * _zoom)) / 2;
        int y = (this.Height - (int)(_image.Height * _zoom)) / 2;
        if (this.HScroll)
            x = 0;
        if (this.VScroll)
            y = 0;
        // Calculate the panning amount to keep the image centered
        Matrix mx = new Matrix(_zoom, 0, 0, _zoom, x, y);
        mx.Translate(this.AutoScrollPosition.X / _zoom - x, this.AutoScrollPosition.Y / _zoom- y);
        e.Graphics.Transform = mx;
        e.Graphics.InterpolationMode = _interpolationMode;
        // Calculate the top-left corner of the image
        
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(_image, new Rectangle(x, y, this._image.Width, this._image.Height), 0, 0, _image.Width, _image.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);`
```